# Mostrar PDF la momento de hacer clic en boton javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

tengo este codigo donde se trabaja para ver imagenesm si funciona,
Peroi intento realizar exactamente  lo mismo, pero con PDF.
Ejemplo cambiando
imagen.jpg --> por --> archivo.pdf

La imagen si la muestra, pero si lo cambio por un archivo PDF no funciona.
Alguna idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(image){
  var imghol = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
  imghol.src = image;
}
</script>

<div class="ADS2">
    <h2>Vehicle Part</h2>
    <p>Please select a part you wish to find;</p>
    <div class="vertical_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="FS" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('imagen.jpg');">pdf1</a></li>
            <li><a id="RS" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('imagen2.png')">pdf2</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="imageholder"><img id="imageHolder" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mostrar un PDF no sigue la misma logica de mostrar imagenes (las imagenes se pueden incluir con un simple tag, los PDF no). Puedes considerar si es un PDF abrirlo en una nueva ventana y dejar que el browser lo muestre?

Comment: Hola, respondiendo, mi idea es que el PDF se muestre en la misma ventana, es decir, en un DIV.

Comment: Tal vez usando un elemento `<frame>`. ¿Lo has intentado?

Comment: Si, solo que trato de evitar los frames, u objects, por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: Intentaste con un embed?

Answer (score 1):

La opcion mas sencilla es incrustarlo dentro de un iframe:

```
<iframe src="test.pdf" style="width:100%;height:700px;"></iframe>
```

Pero existe otra opcion bastante estandar usando `object`:

```
<object id="pdfHolder" data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
   <!-- alternative content -->
</object>
```

El contenido alternativo se activa si el `object` de tipo PDF no esta soportado, ahi puede ir una imagen preview del PDF con un link de descarga del mismo, por ejemplo.

```
<object id="pdfHolder" data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
   <a href="test.pdf" download ><img src="test.pdf.preview.jpg" ></a>
</object>
```